# Structural Breaks/Changepoints vs Regimes

Tags: market-regimes

Structural break is defined as(taken from Introduction to Econometrics by Stock & Watson):

> When the population regression function changes over the course of the sample"

> Breaks can arise either from a discrete change in the population regression coefficients at a distinct date or from a gradual evolution of the coefficients over longer period of time.

Change points and changepoint detection is defined as:([source](https://%20https://kevin-kotze.gitlab.io/tsm/ts-2-note/):)

> A particular change point test seeks to
> identify the specific period of time that relates to a change in the
> probability distribution of a stochastic process or time series. In
> general, the problem concerns both detecting whether or not a change
> has occurred, or whether several changes might have occurred, and
> identifying the times of any such changes.
>
> To establish a relatively general framework for the detection of a
> change point, we can assume that we have an ordered sequence of data,
> $y_t=\{y_1, \ldots, y_T\}$. A change point is then said to
> arise within this dataset when there exists a time, $\tau \in\{1, \ldots, T-1\}$, such that the statistical properties of $\{y_1, \ldots, y_\tau\}$ and $\{y_{\tau+1}, \ldots, y_T\}$
> are different in some way. Extending this idea for a single change
> point to multiple changes, we can allow for $m$ change points, that
> are associated with positions, $\tau_{1: m}=\{\tau_1, \ldots, \tau_m\}$. Each change point position is then ordered so that
> $\tau_i<\tau_j$ if, and only if, $i<j$. Consequently the $m$ change
> points will split the data into $m+1$ segments, where the $i$ th
> segment may be summarised by a set of parameters. The parameters
> associated with the $i$ th segment will be denoted $\{\theta_i, \phi_i\}$, where $\phi_i$ is a possible set of nuisance
> parameters and $\theta_i$ is the set of parameters that may describe
> the change. In this case, we typically want to test how many segments
> are needed to provide the best representation of the data generating
> process.

They discuss tests for finding changes in mean and/or variance, and that structural breaks are a specific case of changepoints.

Here are a few definitions I found for regimes ,regimes shifts/switch, and regime switching models:

1. regimes are " periods of fairly persistent market conditions." (from [Two Sigma](https://www.twosigma.com/articles/a-machine-learning-approach-to-regime-modeling/))
2. 

> Regime shifts are large, abrupt, persistent changes in the structure
> and function of ecosystems, the climate, financial systems or other
> complex systems. A regime is a characteristic behaviour of a system
> which is maintained by mutually reinforced processes or feedbacks.
> Regimes are considered persistent relative to the time period over
> which the shift occurs. The change of regimes, or the shift, usually
> occurs when a smooth change in an internal process (feedback) or a
> single disturbance (external shocks) triggers a completely different
> system behavior.
> (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regime_shift#cite_note-auto1-5))

3. 

> Regime Shift Model acknowledges that a time series can exist in
> different "states," each characterized by its unique set of
> statistical properties. These states represent distinct periods in
> which the behavior of the data undergoes significant changes. The
> transition from one state to another is governed by specific processes
> or variables, reflecting shifts triggered by fundamental changes in
> macroeconomic variables, policies, or regulations.[(from Wright Research)](https://www.wrightresearch.in/blog/regime-shift-models-av/)

4. 

> Regime‐switching models are time-series models in which parameters are
> allowed to take on different values in each of some fixed number of
> “regimes.”[(taken from here)](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-0-387-30440-3_165)

I am wondering what the connection is between structural breaks/changepoints and regime/regime switching/regime switching models? And whether changepoint detection can be used for  regime switching?
When I see that last definition for regime switching model say "parameters are allowed to take on different values", that does seem similar to structural breaks being a change in regression coefficients?

Comment: hi: it's an interesting question but I don't know if it really matters. regime switching tends to mean that the "state" of your process is different. For example, bearish could be one regime and bullish could be another. A regime switching model tries to "capture" what regime the process is currently in. changepoint-structural breaks tend to have more to do with a parameter change. For example, maybe one of the coefficients in the model suddenly changes. This is not an answer but, as I said, it really doesn't matter how one defines the change. The technique one uses is all that matters.

Comment: kim and nelson have a book on regime switching in time-series models that I remember being pretty decent. It's now old though so there might be newer ones. James Hamilton wrote a paper on regime switching in the late 80's that is quite well known. Maybe look at those if you are interested in regime switching.

Comment: Thanks. I guess its not too important in practice. Since there's similarities I am just curious how things fit together. And also if they're the same thing, everything I am reading about changepoints/SB transfers over to how I understand regimes. I will check those books out, I appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: Seems like when you say "change in state", I can view that as a state in a state space model.

Comment: yes, in regime switching, often the technique is applied by estimating a state space model. ( the kim and nelson book covers this ). but hmm's are another framework where the state needs to be inferred. So, it doesn't necessarily have to be state space framework. I think, for practical purposes, the best thing to do is look at an example such as hamilton's. let me see if I can find the Hamilton paper.

Comment: this isn't the paper I'm referring to but the references at the end have a lot of papers by Hamilton. One of them is probably it. I think it was 1988 or 1989. https://econweb.ucsd.edu/~jhamilto/palgrav1.pdf

Comment: This is what I was referring to but I couldn't find a free copy. https://www.jstor.org/stable/1912559